# How to get first three dates of next month using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am developing UI automation framework using webDriver/Selenium and have a scenario in which I need to get the first,second and third dates (string) of the next month based on the date (date) I get from the application. e.g.. If I get 29/10/2018 in string from application then I need a method in java that will return 01/11/2018 in string and if its 30/10/2018 then 02/11/2018 and its 31/10/2018 then 03/11/2018. At the minute, I have prepared three methods to return the first three dates of the next month and works for me but I believe there is a better way to do it. The way I am doing it as below. Please help

Many Thanks,
Ref

```
private String getFirstDayOfNextMonth(String date)
{
    String firstDay = null;
    try
    {
        Date today = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(today);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, +1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
        Date firstDayOfNextMonth = calendar.getTime();
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        firstDay = sdf.format(firstDayOfNextMonth);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        log.error("Not able to return first day of next month", e);
    }
    return firstDay;
}

private String getSecondDayOfNextMonth(String date)
{
    String secondDay = null;
    try
    {
        Date today = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(today);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, +1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        Date firstDayOfNextMonth = calendar.getTime();
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        secondDay = sdf.format(firstDayOfNextMonth);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        log.error("Not able to return second day of next month", e);
    }
    return secondDay;
}

private String getThirdDayOfNextMonth(String date)
{
    String thirdDay = null;
    try
    {
        Date today = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(today);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, +1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
        Date firstDayOfNextMonth = calendar.getTime();
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        thirdDay = sdf.format(firstDayOfNextMonth);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        log.error("Not able to return third day of next month", e);
    }
    return thirdDay;
}
```

Comment: Well, if you're looking for a better way, the first step would be to start using the Java 8 date/time API instead of using the legacy approach. The second step would probably be to factor out the shared logic that you have in all three methods, and put it in a separate method.

Comment: You should explain the logic connecting first dates with result dates. Is it based on last-day-of-month, next-to-last-day-minus, and so on?

Answer (score 2):

You can use java 8 Time api 
Here is an example :

```
 public static List<LocalDate> getLocalDate(final LocalDate localDate) {
        final LocalDate localDateStartingWithNextMonth = 
                  localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth());
   return IntStream.range(0, 3)
                .boxed().map(localDateStartingWithNextMonth::plusDays)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

      List<LocalDate> localDate = getLocalDate(LocalDate.of(2018, 10, 29));
```

You will get the response :

```
2018-11-01
2018-11-02
2018-11-03
```

I think this is helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java 8 to do this. I recommend creating one method with a parameter of `dayOfMonthOffset` that you can pass if you want the 1st, 2nd or 10th day of the next month. Below is the code:

```
public static String getDayOfNextMonth(int dayOfMonthOffset, String inDate) 
{
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(inDate, format)
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth())
            .withDayOfMonth(dayOfMonthOffset);

    return date.format(format);
}
```

In this we use the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class to parse the entered date (given in the format dd/MM/yyyy), adjust the month with [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html), and then use `withDayOfMonth` to set which day of next month we want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I can see 'ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")' in red in below line of code. How to resolve this. `DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Comment: Found the issue. Its happening as I have already used joda-time so it's conflicting. I wonder if I can implement same method using Joda-time instead

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, you really should use the [Date/Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) available since Java 8. More specifically, you should use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) together with [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for conversion between text and date.

So let's take this in steps. Consider the following formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

This allows you for easy conversion between `LocalDate` and your strings.

```
private static LocalDate stringToLocalDate(String dateAsString) {
  return LocalDate.parse(dateAsString, FORMATTER);
}
```

The above method would convert a date in your string format to a `LocalDate`.

```
private static List<String> localDatesToString(List<LocalDate> dates) {
  return dates.stream().map(FORMATTER::format).collect(toList());
}
```

The above goes the other way around, except that it iterates over a list and converts the dates to your string format.

```
private static List<LocalDate> firstThreeDaysNextMonth(LocalDate date) {
  final LocalDate startOfNextMonth = date.plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1);
  return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 2).mapToObj(startOfNextMonth::plusDays).collect(toList());
}
```

The above method returns the first three days of the next month. The code is quite easy to understand, but first we calculate the first day of the next month. We then stream over 0, 1, and 2 and add each number to that date.

Finally, this main method demonstrates usage of the three methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final String dateAsString = "29/10/2018";
  LocalDate date = stringToLocalDate(dateAsString);
  List<LocalDate> firstThreeDaysNextMonth = firstThreeDaysNextMonth(date);
  List<String> firstThreeDaysNextMonthAsStrings = localDatesToString(firstThreeDaysNextMonth);
  System.out.println(firstThreeDaysNextMonthAsStrings);
}
```

It outputs:

> [01/11/2018, 02/11/2018, 03/11/2018]